# Can we make an "Outerable" Attribute?

Tags: data, meta-programming

We can declare a function to have the `Listable` Attribute so that it automatically threads over lists in a particular way. For functions of multiple arguments it acts like an inner product or `MapThread`. I would like something similar but with `Outer`. Naively one could do

```
f[l1_List, l2_List] := Outer[f, l1, l2];
```

but the `Listable` attribute is slightly nicer.

Supposing g is `Listable`. Not only does the threading accept a `List` in both arguments

```
g[{1, 2}, {3, 4}]
(* {g[1, 3], g[2, 4]} *)
```

but it can accept a `List` in any combination of arguments!

```
g[{1, 2}, 3]
(* {g[1, 3], g[2, 3]} *)
```

```
g[{1, 2}, 3, {4, 5}]
(* {g[1, 3, 4], g[2, 3, 5]} *)
```

```
g[1, {2, 3, 4}, 5, {6, 7, 8}]
(* {g[1, 2, 5, 6], g[1, 3, 5, 7], g[1, 4, 5, 8]} *)
```

To replicate this behavior for a function that automatically `Outer`s itself one would have to

```
f[arg1 : Except[List], arg2_List] := Outer[f[arg1, #]&, arg2];
f[arg1_List, arg2 : Except[List]] := Outer[f[#, arg2]&, arg1];
f[arg1_List, arg2_List] := Outer[f, arg1, arg2];
```

for a function of only 2 arguments. There would be 7 definitions for a function of 3 arguments and so on.

**Question**
Can we autogenerate these definitions for a function with a known but arbitrary number of (intended) arguments such that instead of typing out the above code block, one could just use

```
MakeAutoOuterable[f, 2]
```

and `f` would act accordingly?

---

Heres some potentially relevant context on my usage. I have datasets that are a function of 3 values, whether or not we used a resistor, the temperature they were taken at, and the current we used. So `data["withR", "300K", "200mA"]` returns the dataset taken with the resistor, at 300 Kelvin, and 200 milliamps. `data[{"withR", "noR"}, "250K", {"200mA", "210mA", "220mA"}]` returns a matrix of (6 total) datasets which I can then feed to plotting functions etc.

This seems like a job for `Dataset`, but I can't quite figure out the "correct workflow" to get this functionality (using `Dataset` is hard!). Instead this DownValue based approach has worked well but I'm tired of writing the definitions manually and not quite smart enough to work out MakeAutoOuterable by myself!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Somehow `Outerable` ought to conform to the syntax of `Outer`.  The following does it for the form `f[list1, list2,...]`:

```
ClearAll[outerify];
SetAttributes[outerify, HoldAll];
outerify[def : Verbatim[SetDelayed][f_[a___], body_]] := (
   f[args__List] := Outer[f, args];
   def
   );
```

However, on the basis of the examples, the OP seems to desire a combination of `Listable` and `Outerable`, which the following does:

```
ClearAll[outerify];
SetAttributes[outerify, HoldAll];
outerify[def : Verbatim[SetDelayed][f_[a___], body_]] := Module[{g},
   SetAttributes[g, HoldAll];
   f[args__] /; MemberQ[{args}, _List] :=
    
    With[{ff = 
       Evaluate[
          Module[{k = 0}, 
           Replace[g[args], _List :> With[{n = ++k}, Slot[n] /; True],
             1]]] & /. g -> f},
     Outer[ff, ##] & @@ Cases[{args}, _List]
     ];
   def
   ];
```

Example:

```
ClearAll[ff];
outerify[ff[x_, y_] := 
  Piecewise[{{x, x != 0}}] + Piecewise[{{y, y != 0}}]]

ff[Range[5], 10 Range@5]

(*
{{11, 21, 31, 41, 51},
 {12, 22, 32, 42, 52},
 {13, 23, 33, 43, 53},
 {14, 24, 34, 44, 54},
 {15, 25, 35, 45, 55}}
*)

ff[Range[5], 10]

(*  {11, 12, 13, 14, 15}  *)
```

It does an outer product of ragged arrays:

```
ClearAll[gg];
outerify[gg[x_, y_, z_] := x + y + z];
gg[100 {{1, 2}, {1}, {1, 2, 3}}, 10 {{1, 2, 3}, {}}, Range[4, 5]]

(*
{{{{{114, 115}, {124, 125}, {134, 135}}, {}},
  {{{214, 215}, {224, 225}, {234, 235}}, {}}},
 {{{{114, 115}, {124, 125}, {134, 135}}, {}}},
 {{{{114, 115}, {124, 125}, {134, 135}}, {}},
  {{{214, 215}, {224, 225}, {234, 235}}, {}},
  {{{314, 315}, {324, 325}, {334, 335}}, {}}}}
*)
```

Answer (score 10):

```
ClearAll[makeOuterable]
SetAttributes[makeOuterable, HoldFirst]
makeOuterable[f_] := Distribute[f@##, List] &
```

**Examples:**

```
Operate[makeOuterable, f[3, {1, 2}, 5]]
```

> ```
> {f[3, 1, 5], f[3, 2, 5]}
> ```

```
makeOuterable[h][3, {1, 2}, 5]
```

> ```
> {h[3, 1, 5], h[3, 2, 5]}
> ```

```
makeOuterable[h][{1, 2}, {3}]
```

> ```
> {h[1, 3], h[2, 3]}
> ```

```
makeOuterable[h][{1, 2}, {3, 4}]
```

> ```
> {h[1, 3], h[1, 4], h[2, 3], h[2, 4]}
> ```

```
makeOuterable[h][3, {1, 2}]
```

> ```
> {h[3, 1], h[3, 2]}
> ```

```
makeOuterable[h][{1, 2}, 3]
```

> ```
> {h[1, 3], h[2, 3]}
> ```

Comment: Wow that was fast. I'll wait till tomorrow to accept the answer in case others would like to post as well. Is there an easy way for this to output a tensor and not a flat list? Or would it require manually looking at the arguments and reparsing using `ArrayReshape`?

Comment: @TannerLegvold, you can use the third and fourth arguments of `Dsitribute` to re-shape the result: for example, `ClearAll[makeOuterable2];
SetAttributes[makeOuterable2, HoldFirst]
makeOuterable2[f_] := 
 Distribute[f@##, List, f, 
   Module[{x = Length /@ Reverse[Flatten[{#}] & /@ {##}]}, 
    ArrayReshape[{##}, x] &]] &`

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[outeR]
outeR[f_] := Outer[f, ##] & @@ Replace[{##}, x_?AtomQ :> {x}, 1, Heads -> False] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
outeR[h][3, {1, 2}]
```

> ```
>  {{h[3, 1], h[3, 2]}}
> ```

```
outeR[h][{1, 2}, 3]
```

> ```
>  {{h[1, 3]}, {h[2, 3]}}
> ```

```
outeR[h][{1, 2}, x, {a, b}]
```

> ```
>  {{{h[1, x, a], h[1, x, b]}}, {{h[2, x, a], h[2, x, b]}}}
> ```

```
outeR[h][a, {1, 2}, x]
```

> ```
>  {{{h[a, 1, x]}, {h[a, 2, x]}}}
> ```

```
outeR[Plus][a, {1, 2}, x]
```

> ```
> {{{1 + a + x}, {2 + a + x}}}
> ```

```
outeR[Plus][{1, 2}, x, {a, b}]
```

> ```
> {{{1 + a + x, 1 + b + x}}, {{2 + a + x, 2 + b + x}}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Define [`UpValues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues.html) for `mkOuterable` as

```
ClearAll[mkOuterable]
mkOuterable /: Outer[mkOuterable[f_], a__] := 
 Outer[f, ##] & @@ Replace[{a}, x_?AtomQ :> {x}, 1, Heads -> False]
```

and wrap the first argument of `Outer` with `mkOuterable`.

***Examples:***

```
Outer[mkOuterable@u, x, {1, 2}, {a, b}]
```

> ```
> {{{u[x, 1, a], u[x, 1, b]}, {u[x, 2, a], u[x, 2, b]}}}
> ```

```
Outer[mkOuterable@u, {1, 2}, x, {a, b}]
```

> ```
> {{{u[1, x, a], u[1, x, b]}}, {{u[2, x, a], u[2, x, b]}}}
> ```

```
Outer[mkOuterable@u, {1, 2}, {a, b}, x]
```

> ```
> {{{u[1, a, x]}, {u[1, b, x]}}, {{u[2, a, x]}, {u[2, b, x]}}}
> ```

```
Outer[mkOuterable@Plus, x, {1, 2}, {a, b}]
```

> ```
> {{{1 + a + x, 1 + b + x}, {2 + a + x, 2 + b + x}}}
> ```

```
Outer[mkOuterable@Plus, {1, 2}, x, {a, b}]
```

> ```
> {{{1 + a + x, 1 + b + x}}, {{2 + a + x, 2 + b + x}}}
> ```

```
Outer[mkOuterable@Plus, {1, 2}, {a, b}, x]
```

> ```
> {{{1 + a + x}, {1 + b + x}}, {{2 + a + x}, {2 + b + x}}}
> ```